# Are global variables actually global in their RAM share behavior?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, global

In a multithreaded application, does each thread have its own copy of a given global variable for performance reasons, or can each thread only read/write into the same version?

If the answer is the former, does a mutex Lock(), followed by Unlock() guarantee copying the data into the global variable?

Language is Cpp. Compiler is the default VS compiler. OS is Windows. Target CPU is modern 5+ core.

Many comments suggest that unless otherwise specified, a global variable has only a single copy throughout the application running instance. Is this code totally safe with zero need for any synchronization or any other data accessing protection mechanism?

(C++ pseudo-code. It isn't best-practice, I am just trying to make sure of certain concepts as part of an inquiry.)

```
//In MyApplication.cpp
    int Variable1 = 0;
    bool ThreadAFinished = false;

    void ThreadAFunction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Variable1++;

            if (Variable1 == 1000)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        ThreadAFinished = true;
    }
    void ThreadBFunction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ThreadAFinished)
            {
                if (Variable1 < 1000)
                {
                    printf("ERROR");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("TEST PASSED");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253238/discussion-on-question-by-physician-are-global-variables-actually-global-in-thei); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...does each thread has its own 'copy' of the global variable...

Yes, but No.

"Yes" because, at a *low level,* at a level that lies beneath anything that has to do with the C++ language, updates to a variable by different threads can be *cached* in different memory locations.

"No" because, "cache" is not part of the explanation of how the C++ language works. It is not part of the language's [*memory model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)).

The way the memory model explains it, there is one and only one copy of any given global variable. But when different threads update global variables with no explicit [*synchronization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)), then threads are allowed to disagree on the order in which updates to the different variables happened. That disagreement can allow threads to see inconsistent, sometimes corrupt, views of *shared* data, but it also allows the system to make the most efficient use of the hardware caches, and get the best performance when threads are accessing their *private* data.

> does a mutex Lock(), followed by Unlock() guarantee copying the data into the global variable proper?

Locking and unlocking mutexes is one kind of explicit synchronization that a program can use to ensure that different threads see consistent views of the same shared data structure.

If you have some shared, global structure, and if every thread locks *the same* shared, global mutex whenever they access the structure, then the structure is safe. What "safe" means is, Every time thread A locks the mutex, then it will see the data structure in the same exact state that some other thread left it in just before the other thread released the mutex.

If any thread access the structure without locking the mutex though, even if it's a read-only access, the other thread *could* see the structure in an inconsistent state because different parts of what it sees could come from different levels of "cache."

Comment: So the answer is no. The mere usage of Lock(), Unlock() doesn't guarantee a globally visible variable edit. Only using the exact same mutex by each thread for accessing that global variable will actually do the trick? Am I right?

Comment: @Physician, Correct. _All_ threads should lock the same mutex when they access the same shared data.

Answer (score 2):

Others already commented: you can rely upon having just one copy being accessed by all threads, as long as you don't explicitly make it thread-local.

As for the thread race problems, please be aware, that its not only the compiler optimizing to different instruction ordering, but also memory and register caching, that will trick you. **Do not expect the volatile modifier to solve those problems** ... it also does not guarantee proper behavior in all situations.

There are good (short and understandable) articles about **memory fencing / memory barrier** in wikipedia and standard libs also have some things available for you: search for "**Atomic operations library**"

Comment: @Physician: "Let me now add this code, and ask whether ..." - Stack Overflow is NOT a chat. You asked a question, then got an answer. After that the only edits allowable for the question are the ones which **improves** it (fixing grammar, fixing stylistic problems, and so on). You should NOT edit the question post for **change** its question specification or add new questions into the post. If you have more questions, then create new question post. (But make sure that your have searched for the topic you want to ask about. E.g. by "c++ access global variable from several threads").

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple copies of the same global variable. Each processor has its own data cache, and the cache will typically hold a separate copy of whatever data the processor is using.

That's one of the reasons why you have to provide synchronization between threads that access the same data; one thread can write to the data in its local cache, and another thread reads the "same" data, either from its own local cache or from memory, and doesn't see the change that the other thread made.

The code in the question has a data race: one thread updates the global variables, and another thread reads the values of the global variables. The behavior of the program is undefined. The simplest fix is to change the types of the two global variables to make them atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> Variable1 = 0;
std::atomic<bool> ThreaedAFinished = false;
```

Now the compiler (well, the runtime library) will provide the appropriate code to ensure that caches get flushed and reloaded appropriately, so that the two global variables act like there is only one copy of each.